# MD5 in Java Micro Edition

Tags: java-me, md5

I have a problem.
I must get a md5 hash of string in Java ME.
I have that code

```
   public static String md5(String input) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    String res = "";
    try {
        MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        algorithm.reset();
        algorithm.update(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] md5 = algorithm.digest();
        return md5.toString();
        }
     catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {}
    return res;
}
```

But **MessageDigest.update()** and **MessageDigest.digest()** accept only 3 arguments.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two other arguments are `offset` and `len`, which you can set to `0` and *the length of the byte buffer* respectively.

Comment: `algorithm.update(input.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, input.length());` but  `byte[] md5 = algorithm.digest();` when get 3 args returns int

Comment: If you read the documentation you will notice that .digest's first argument should be an output buffer.